# Run a system wide keylogger

Tags: macos

I'd like to run a system wide keylogger (For purely educational/backup purposes of course) on Mac OS Sierra, how can I do it without buying expensive apps for that?

I've been using [logKext from github](https://github.com/SlEePlEs5/logKext) but it stopped working after upgrade from El Capitan.

I almost got it working, but console is showing me `Error: Daemon must run as root.`, I've tried to `sudo chown root` each file but to no use.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Update:
I got it running but it's not logging any keys. Console shows no errors connected with it.

Comment: What have you already tried/attempted to do this?  Editing your question with this info helps prevent answers that propose solutions you've already tried.

Comment: Have you tried disabling SIP to get logKext to work?

Comment: It'd also be good to know what **you're** definition of _expensive apps_ is? What someone thinks is expensive may not be what you think is expensive! Maybe a couple of examples would be good.

Comment: @books453 yes I did, I keep it disabled.

Comment: @Monomeeth Ok, maybe in other words: I don't want to buy apps for that at all - open source is best.

Comment: Also: what is your end goal? Perhaps there is another way of obtaining it instead of running a system wide keylogger?

Comment: Logging every keystroke from every text field

Answer (score -2):

try to:
rebbot with CMD + R 
launch Terminal
I guess system gonna ask for the administration password
then type : csrutil disable
then reboot your system normaly
and instal Logkext

Comment: What does this disable??

Comment: It was asked in the comments "Have you tried disabling SIP to get logKext to work?" and was answered with this comment "yes I did, I keep it disabled." by the OP, so your answer is not at all relevant to the issue! Also you said "I guess system gonna ask for the administration password", well a password is not necessary and all that's necessary is to simple type `csrutil disable` and press _enter_.